# May I let the user to upload 1 or more images into the customized Google form and store the images into specific google sheet cells

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML code that im using to customize my google form and i want the user to upload 1 or more images and store them into google sheets. I'm using a customized Google form in HTML and JS.

I would also like to send email reminders to the user. I-m using appscript because i cant use API.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang ="en">
      <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel = "shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href="/assets/dcode.css">
      <style>
      </style>
    
      <title>Nueva Auditoria 5 Ss</title>
      </head>
    <body class="" onload="start();">
        
    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSe0SoGhRpLqNpCOBG0Gt9hjGfcZ7zOs3RdVlLpMWXMZuyGM4A/formResponse" method="post">
        
        <div class="form-element">
         <span>Nombre del Auditado:</span>
         <input type="text" name="entry.1108016119" placeholder="Nombre del Auditado:" required>
         </div>
        
        <div class="form-element">
         <span>Email del Auditado:</span>
         <input type="text" name="entry.332567149" placeholder="Email del Auditado:" required>
         </div>
        
         <div class="form-element">
         <span>Shop a la que pertenece:</span>
         <input type="text" name="entry.537147742" placeholder="Shop a la que pertenece:" required>
         </div>
        
        <div class="form-element">
         <span>Area auditada:</span>
         <input type="text" name="entry.56248648" placeholder="Area auditada:" required>
         </div>
        
        <div class="form-element">
         <span>Descripcion de las condiciones encontradas:</span>
         <input type="text" name="entry.558868673" placeholder="Descripcion de las condiciones encontradas:" required>
         </div>
        
        <div class="form-element">
         <span>Acciones:</span>
         <input type="text" name="entry.1907258774" placeholder="Acciones:" required>
         </div>
    
    
         <div class="form-element radio-buttons"></div>
        <span>A que "S" corresponde?</span>
         <label for="Separar">
             <span>Separar</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.370734580" id="Separar" value="Separar">
         </label>
        <label for="Organizar">
             <span>Organizar</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.370734580" id="Organizar" value="Organizar">
         </label>
        <label for="Limpiar">
             <span>Limpiar</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.370734580" id="Limpiar" value="Limpiar">
         </label>
        <label for="Estandarizar">
             <span>Estandarizar</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.370734580" id="Estandarizar" value="Estandarizar">
         </label>
        <label for="Sostener">
             <span>Sostener</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.370734580" id="Sostener" value="Sostener">
         </label>
    
         <!---- Evidencia de las acciones !---->
    
    
        
        <div class="form-element">
         <span>Fecha compromiso:</span>
         <input type="text" name="entry.1005228242" placeholder="Acciones:" required>
         </div>
        
         <div class="form-element radio-buttons"></div>
        <span>Seguimiento PDCA</span>
         <label for="Plan">
             <span>Plan</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.206420434" id="Plan" value="Plan">
         </label>
        <label for="Do">
             <span>Do</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.206420434" id="Do" value="Do">
         </label>
        <label for="Act">
             <span>Act</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.206420434" id="Act" value="Act">
         </label>
        <label for="Check">
             <span>Check</span>
             <input type="radio" name="entry.206420434" id="Check" value="Check">
         </label>
    <br><br>
          
         <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you!